# Push и local notifications in NativeScript. How to make them fullscreen?

Tags: android, mobile, nativescript

I am quite new in android dev and try to make NativeScript (vue) app. 
I've installed plugin local-notifications and listening for pusher. It works and i get notifications and the top of mobile.

But what about push notifications? Push plugin is deprecated and the only i've found needs firebase. Not ready to do that.

So, the reason of the Q is the following. App works in background. And when the event happens (i send notification via pusher) - i want the full-screen notification? Or the App "wakes-up" and opens full-screen with extra data or so. Something like a telephone call.

Where to look? What are the keywords? Is that a splash screen? Please guide me the right way.

Comment: i dont think you can? notifications are the small boxes at the top of the screen. what have you tried so far to get this to work?

Comment: If you want to launch an Activity upon receiving push notification on Android, you will have to send a `data message` from FCM which will not show a notification but will directly invoke the callback, form that call back you must be able to start the activity.

Answer (score 0):

For me i invoke notifications via socketio, from my server through localnotifications and you can invoke the app to wake up i think